# Eigenvectors of a quadratic form restricted to a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

I have a matrix $A\in R^{n\times n}$ which is not symmetric. I am considering a quadratic form $$ \mathbf{x}^{T} A \mathbf{x}$$ where $\mathbf{x} \in V \subset R^{n}$ ($V$ is a linear subspace of $R^n$). I can prove that the quadratic form is negative definite when it is restricted to $V$ (this is not true more generally in $R^n$). Is this enough to claim that $V$ is a subspace of the span of the eigenvectors of $A$ associated with negative-real-part eigenvalues?

More information: When considered on the entire space $R^n$ the matrix $A$ is only negative semi-definite, however when $\mathbf{x}$ is restricted to be in $V$ the quadratic form is negative definite. This is because the null space of $A$ is a complementary space to the range of $A$ in $R^n$ - this is something I have proved but it is a bit cumbersome. I want to figure out if just showing the fact that the quadratic form is negative definite on $V$ (this is something that is pretty easy for the problem I'm considering) is enough to conclude that the range of $A$ is associated with negative-real-part eigenvalues.

Comment: The answer is no because an operator with negative-real-part eigenvalues is not necessarily negative definite.

Comment: you could determine the definiteness of the quadratic form by consider the decomposition $A=S+T$, where $S=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^{\top})$ and $T=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^{\top})$ which are the symmetric and anti-symmetric parts of $A$. Under this you will see that $x^{\top}Ax=x^{\top}Sx$ because $x^{\top}Tx=0$. With $S$ symmetric you get a real spectrum useful to see the sign of $A$.

Comment: Let me clarify: I know that the operator is negative definite on the subspace. That part I have already proved. I want to know if I can use the fact that it's negative definite to deduce that the eigenvalues associated with directions along the subspace are negative. I think the answers above are answering my question in the opposite direction.

Comment: Here, we aren't answering you questions but only we had commented, now, if you have in mind a specific $A$ let us know